# Нет пространства имен (System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard)

Tags: c#, .net, clipboard

Не могу включить использование буфера обмена в программу. Просто выдаёт, что такого нет.

Comment: писал- using System.Windows(дальше не ишет).Forms;

Comment: А проект какого типа создали?

Comment: консольное приложение. Пока что для тестов в консоле работаю. А так делаю приложение win.forms

Comment: Ну всё верно, в шаблоне консольного приложения эта сборка не подключается, смотрите ответ, подключите сборку вручную

Comment: У вас батник, или проэкт?

Comment: проект в вижуал студио

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для использования этого класса требуется подключить сборку `System.Windows.Forms`, убедитесь что она подключена - в окне `Solution Explorer`, в вашем проекте откройте вкладку `References`

Посмотреть, к какой сборке принадлежит тот или иной тип можно на MSDN, например, [Класс `Clipboard`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **Пространство имен:**   System.Windows.Forms
>   **Сборка:** System.Windows.Forms (в System.Windows.Forms.dll)

Comment: Плюс msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.120).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте подключить сборку `System.Windows.Forms.dll`.

Comment: Очень кототкий ответ, лучше добавить ссылку где это в картинках показано. Тут и правда всё просто, но ваш ответ могут неоценить.

Answer (score 0):

нажать пкм по "ссылки" в обозревателе решении, далее- "добавить ссылку" и ставим галочку на против нужной сборки